# PHP/ CSS changes needed

Tags: php, css

I am starting to dive into some PHP on my wordpress and I'm having some trouble

What I am trying to do:
1. add a button to the bottom of each image in an image gallery there are 4 rows and 4 columns

What I have done:

1. I created a child theme and copied my page.php file to my child them
2. added a div like this to my my php file: `<div class="button"></div>`
3. added the following CSS to my style.css

   ```css
   .page-id-482  div.button{
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     border: none;
     color: white;
     padding: 15px 32px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 16px;
     margin: 4px 2px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 15px;
   }
   ```

I am stuck as to what I need to do to add a button to each image in the gallery. Every time I change the CSS I cant get the button to move. It currently sits where I placed it in the PHP. I need to change my CSS but I'm not sure how.

See image:

[image]

Comment: _"what I need to do to add a button to each image in the gallery"_  what generates the gallery? Presumably, you'd need to edit that code

Comment: True...those php files are through the visual composer for each page and I don't feel like breaking a plugin. Looks like im gonna make a page from scratch!

Comment: Well.... not necessarily. You could inject some buttons with JS (or even CSS) and add event listeners to handle the click events